# Injection that works on wildfly does not work with weld-se. Other injections work on both

Tags: java, cdi, code-injection, weld

I am having difficulty getting an injection to work running in a standalone weld container. It is in library code that is also run on a wildfly container where it works. Other injects work in the weld container, just this one is giving me trouble. I’ve tried specifically adding both the  class and the interface via the SeContainerInitializer. And I’ve tried creating a factory and using a produces method.

Annotation on the class ( it is the javax.inject.Singleton). It has a public no argument constructor

```
package com.ticomgeo.ftc.util;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory; 
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

  @Singleton
  public class ExecutorImpl implements RITExecutor {
  private  static  ScheduledExecutorService TIMER = executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getClassName());

  public ExecutorImpl() { super(); }

  @PostConstruct
    void initImpl() {     
    LOG.info("======================================Initializedingleton");
  }

  @Override
  public  void dispose() {
    TIMER.shutdownNow();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isDisposed() {
    return TIMER.isShutdown();
  }

  @Override
  public <J> ScheduledFuture<J> schedule(Callable<J> job, long delay, TimeUnit unit) {
    return TIMER.schedule(job, delay, unit);
  }

  @Override
  public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(Runnable job, long delay, TimeUnit unit) {
    return TIMER.schedule(job, delay, unit);
  }

  @Override
  public <J> Future<J> submit(Callable<J> job) {
    return TIMER.submit(job);
  }

  @Override
  public  Future<?> submit(Runnable job) {
    return TIMER.submit(job);
  }

  @Override
  public  <J> Future<J> submit(Runnable job, J result) {
    return TIMER.submit(job, result);
  }
}
```

Interface

```
package com.ticomgeo.ftc.util;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public interface RITExecutor {
    void dispose();

    boolean isDisposed();

    <J> ScheduledFuture<J> schedule(Callable<J> job, long delay, TimeUnit unit);

    ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(Runnable job, long delay, TimeUnit unit);

    <J> Future<J> submit(Callable<J> job);

    Future<?> submit(Runnable job);

    <J> Future<J> submit(Runnable job, J result);
}
```

Injection

```
@Inject
RITExecutor executor;
```

Weld bootstrap

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SeContainerInitializer initializer = SeContainerInitializer.newInstance();
    /* disable discovery and register classes manually */
    try (SeContainer container = initializer.disableDiscovery()
        .addPackages(FTCServer.class)
        .addPackages(RITServer.class)
        .addPackages(Config.class)
        .addBeanClasses(ExecutorImpl.class, RITExecutor.class)
        .addPackages(AbstractConnection.class)
        .initialize()) {
    container.select(RITServer.class);
}
```

When I try to access the injected bean in the weld-se instance I get a null pointer exception. I have no problems with it on the wildfly instance. There are no errors during deployment.

I have a beans.xml file in all my jars though I assume that is super-ceded by the SeContainerInitializer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
   bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

I am using weld-se-core 3.0.2.Final. java version "1.8.0_121" AbstractConnection and ExecutorImpl are in the same package and jar file. RITExecutor interface is in another jar file.

I've upgraded to weld 3.0.3.Final, and tried the applicationScope annotation with not chance in behavior.

Comment: Two things, firstly try and resolve the bean via `container.select(RITExecutor.class).get()` - if it doesn't work, CDI is not finding the bean at all, it it works we move to point two which is the class where you try to inject it into. Can you share that one as well? Might be it's not found hence no injection is performed (hence the field remains null)

Comment: Out of java-ee context, it may be the case that weld fails to detect the `javax.inject.Singleton` as an appropriate CDI scope, and hence ignores the bean. Can you use `javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped` scope?

Comment: ApplicationScoped is not in the weld library. I would have to import the javaee api. Would relying on classes in that package outside of a jee container be problematic?

Comment: silarus, where do I obtain a reference to the container object.

Comment: I am finding for SE that I need to actually call a method on the bean for it to initialize and process the '   @PostConstruct' seems weld SE is taking the lazy init approach at least for  SeContainerInitializer.newInstance().disableDiscovery()

Answer (score 0):

This is my test scenario. `PostConstruct` works fine on select of the bean.

```

```
package org.dpp.cdi.singleton;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.inject.se.SeContainer;
import javax.enterprise.inject.se.SeContainerInitializer;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld;

/**
 *
 * @author mochieng
 */
public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SeContainerInitializer weld = Weld.newInstance();
        try (SeContainer se = weld.disableDiscovery().addBeanClasses(TestServiceImpl.class).initialize()) {
            TestService service = se.select(TestService.class).get();
        }
    }

    public static interface TestService {

        void doTest();
    }

    @Singleton
    public static class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

        private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TestServiceImpl.class.getName());

        @PostConstruct
        void initImpl() {
            LOG.info("Initialized singleton");
        }

        @Override
        public void doTest() {
            LOG.info("Singleton called");
        }
    }
}
```

```

And maven dependencies:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>org.dpp</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-singleton</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
                <artifactId>weld-se-shaded</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.3.Final</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        </properties>
    </project>`

The problem could be your weld version.

Comment: I updgraded to the version of weld you are using and still have the same problem. I can see the log statement from the postconstruct method when running on a JEE container (wildfly 9), but not when running in SE with weld.